# a11y accessible form inputs as buttons

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, radio-button, accessibility

I'm trying to make make my JavaScript quiz app a11y accessible by making it so users can navigate the buttons using the keyboard. The answer options are radio button inputs in a form. I saw an example of this but with images that had been assigned `input type="image"` and `role="button"`, allowing the user to scroll through image elements using <kbd>Tab</kbd> (the images in this example were interactive). Can I apply this same tactic to my radio buttons?

Below is a snippet of my code. It represents the first answer option in a form.

```html
<form class='questionForm'>
 <fieldset role="radiogroup" aria-labelledby="questionText">
   <legend id="questionText">"${STORE[questionNumber].question}" 
   </legend>
   <label for="answer-1" class="answerOption">
   <input id="answer-1" type="radio" role="radio" value="${STORE[questionNumber].answers[0]}" name="answer" aria-required="true">
   <span>${STORE[questionNumber].answers[0]}</span>
   </label>
```

Comment: If you use the appropriate form elements, you don’t need to do anything special, they are keyboard-accessible by default. -- Anyway, please include (a minimal example of) your markup in the question

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was keyboard-accessible by default. I have updated with some code. Could you please give it a look over and tell me if I used the right form elements?

Answer (score 1):

As @unor says, if you use the default form elements, they are already keyboard accessible.

If you use ARIA attributes (including the `role` attribute), just remember that the attributes provide hints to screen readers but they **don't** provide any behavior.  You have to code the behavior yourself.  Slapping a `role="button"` on something will cause the screen reader to announce that it's a button and the user will expect both the <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys to work in activating the button.

You can create your own image based radio buttons if you want, but again, you need to code the keyboard behavior.  All the radio buttons grouped together are one tab stop and navigating between buttons is done with the arrow keys.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#radiobutton.